Hello,can anyone help me regarding grading and source of this hadith mentioned in tafsir Ibn kathir and tafsir abi hatim for Qur'an 65.4?
The Qur'anic verse 65.4 revelation circumstance is mentioned in tafsir of ibn kathir and others like Abu ibn hatim
https://quranx.com/Tafsirs/65.4
Particularly this part-Ibn Abi Hatim recorded a simpler narration than this one from Ubay bin Kab who said, "O Allah's Messenger! When the Ayah in Surat Al-Baqarah was revealed prescribing the Iddah of divorce, some people in Al-Madinah said, There are still some women whose Iddah has not been mentioned in the Qur'an. There are the young, the old whose menstruation is discontinued, and the pregnant.'
And
Ubay bin Ka`b that he said, "O Allah's Messenger! Some women were not mentioned in the Qur'an, the young, the old and the pregnant.''
Are these Hadiths authentic?I have not been able to find anything about chain of transmission for these hadiths
Thanks in advance
Edit- I was able to find chain of transmission of this hadith from respected scholar Ibn Jarir tabari (may Allah have mercy on his soul),I am adding that,can anyone tell me the grading of this?


I'd assume they are mentioned in Tafssir ibn abi Hatim.

Yes the areas @Sassir,but there too I couldn't find chain of narration,the problem is that the book of abi hatim is lost,and the scholars of reconstructed this part from quotation of ibn kathir

Actually ibn Kathir quoted the chain in his tafsir beside that of ibn Jarir at-Tabari and it appears in Mosannaf ibn abi Shaybah too (at least a good part of it) but the ahdith seemingly is mursal.

@Sassir can you explain that a bit?I am not very knowledgeable regarding hadith sciences,I thought that mursal hadiths are which do not come from sahabi of The Prophet (Peace be upon him),ubayy ka'ab was a sahabi,so how is the hadith mursal? I will check mosannaf ibn abi shaybah,thank you for your help, Jazakallah khair.

Do you want to know the authenticity of the hadith or whether marriage to people before menstruation is allowed? Because those are two different things.

@TheZ authenticity of the hadith,I was discussing this issue about child marriage with a friend,he said the hadith is authentic and that is why it is quoted by Ibn Kathir and others,I do not know if that is true because tafsirs also have weak hadiths in them
